# Why am I getting access denied on Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am getting Permission Denied whenever I try to read from my database (I can write)

```
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      "$user_id":{
        ".read": "$user_id == auth.uid",
        ".write": "$user_id == auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is an activity that is supposed to retrieve every user in the database (I have 20)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.shrinkio.Adapter.UserAdapter;
import com.example.shrinkio.R;
import com.example.shrinkio.model.User;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PeopleFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private UserAdapter userAdapter;
    private List<User> mUsers;

    EditText search_bar;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_people, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        search_bar = view.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
        mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), mUsers);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);

        readUsers();
        search_bar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
             searchUsers(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void searchUsers(String s) {
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("user_Id").orderByChild("Name").startAt(s).endAt(s+"\uf8ff");

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUsers.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    mUsers.add(user);
                }
                userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void readUsers(){
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if ( search_bar.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    mUsers.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        mUsers.add(user);
                    }

                }            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

As previously mentioned, I am supposed to get 20 users, on a recycler view, however, no error occurs, but, the activity remains blank and once I check logcat I get the following error.

It does show as an error, but I can't see the posts that are on the db or any user info:

`W/SyncTree: Listen at /Users failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied`

Comment: Please edit the question to show the app code that isn't working the way you expect, along with explanation why you think it should work with the rules you're showing.  We should be able to see exactly how the code matches the rules.

Comment: Let me know if this is good enough

Comment: Please narrow it down to the minimal code that queries the database.  Please read this for help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to be able to search users, you would need to grant read access at the `/Users` level. But because [security rules cascade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security#section-authorization) in the Realtime Database, if you granted such a permission, the deeper restrictive ".read" rules would get ignored allowing any user to read private user data.

```js
"rules": {
  "Users": {
    "$user_id": {
      ".read": "$user_id == auth.uid", // ignored, superseded by /Users/.read rule
      ".write": "$user_id == auth.uid"
    },
    ".read": "auth != null" // logged in users can read everything under /Users
  }
}
```

Instead, I recommend splitting the user data into private user data and public profile data. The public profile would contain non-sensitive information like display name, profile picture, username, hashed email addresses (for "search by email"/Gravatar), etc.

```js
"rules": {
  "Users": {
    "$user_id": {
      ".read": "$user_id == auth.uid", // only the owner can read/write their private data
      ".write": "$user_id == auth.uid"
    }
  },
  "Profiles": {
    "$user_id": {
      ".write": "$user_id == auth.uid" // only the profile owner can update their profile
    },
    ".read": "auth != null" // logged in users can read everything under /Profiles
  }
}
```

On your front-end, you would change your RecyclerView to use `/Profiles` instead.

Comment: Can you send me a chat message so I can send you the whole activity?

Comment: You won't need to send me the whole thing, but you can message me on the [Firebase Community Slack](https://firebase.community).

Comment: Ok so I did that, i dont get the error anymore, but nothing shows up?

Comment: If you opted to use the `/Profiles` method, it is likely that nothing shows up because you have no data stored at `/Profiles` yet. You'll need to move/copy the appropriate data to that location before you'll see anything on your client.

Answer (score 0):

Your security rules require that a user is signed in before they can read/write to the database. Even then, a user can only read or write their own node under `/Users/theirUid`, where `theirUid` is the user ID that Firebase Authentication assigns to them when they first sign in.

Your code makes no use of Firebase Authentication whatsoever. This means that no user is signed in, and thus the read operation on `/Users` gets rejected.

You'll need to make two changes:

1. Use Firebase Authentication to sign the user in. For more on this, see the [documentation for Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth).
2. Either widen what a signed-in user is allowed to read to `/Users` **or** narrow the code to only read `/Users/theirUid`. The latter essentially makes searching impossible.

If you want to allow the user to search the data, but not to read all that data, consider implementing the search functionality in Cloud Functions. Since Cloud Functions run in a trusted environment, they have full access to the data in the database. But since your code runs on a server, you can be sure that users can only access what your code allows.

Comment: The users is logged in, but I get the error still, how do I make the second change?

Comment: The most stressful thing is that I'm able to write, but not read.

Comment: If the user is logged in, that still leaves #2 from my answer. Since you're not granting read permission to `/User`, the listener on `/User` is rejected. You will have to read from `/User/$uid`, or if you want to implement search do something like I suggest in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Can you please write how that would look?